# Rank-2n tensor algebra eigenvalue equation

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

Im interested in resources and work done on the eigenvalue equation for rank-2n tensors:
$$
M_{ij}A_{j} = \lambda A_{i} \\
$$
$$
M_{ijkl}A_{kl} = \lambda A_{ij} \\
$$ 
$$
M_{ijklmn}A_{lmn} = \lambda A_{ijk}
$$
etc... for the first one, it isn't too hard to find info... but for all the rest I can't seem to find much.  Are there any recommendations for analysis on these equations?  Thanks.

Comment: maybe [here](http://elc2.lci.kent.edu/tmp/Peter__Palffy-Muhoray_2007_02_03_02_33_15.pdf) you can find something.